# 240 volt outlet powered by two insulated wires and one bare ground wire

Tags: electrical

I have a 240v radial arm saw powered by a 240v outlet installed by a licensed electrician. This outlet is powered by 2 20 amp breakers ganged at the panel. The wire to the 240v outlet only has 3 wires. 2 are insulated (white and grey) and the third is a bare ground wire. There are 120v between each insulated wire and the bare ground wire. Can I add a 120v outlet by splicing it to 
one of the insulated wires and the bare ground wire or is this unsafe because I actually need an insulated neutral wire plus the bare copper ground wire?

Comment: Was this wiring run using a *cable*, or *individual wires* inside a *conduit*?

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to the community.

No. you need another insulated neutral wire. You should not use a ground wire as neutral, and you should not use bare wire as a current carrying conductor.

Comment: In addendum - You are describing 2 different circuits. One a 240V circuit which operates on 240V and requires 2 - phase (hot) conductors and  a ground. The second is a 240/120V which operates machinery with the need for both a 240V circuit and a 120V circuit. This will need 2 - phase conductors, one neutral and a ground, and the ground cannot be used as a neutral.